# How to pause JavaScript execution in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, iframe, browser

I have the following scenario:

- Main page
- Nested page
- Common JS file (which is included in both pages)

The nested page is subsequently loaded into an iframe of the main page. Both pages invoke a function from the common JS file on page load.

**Live demo:**
http://www.ecmazing.com/misc/pause-execution/mainpage.html
http://www.ecmazing.com/misc/pause-execution/nestedpage.html
http://www.ecmazing.com/misc/pause-execution/common.js

The common JS file contains one global function which paints the H1 element red. I would like to pause execution at the beginning of that function, so that the execution is paused while the H1 element is still black.

### How to do it on the main page:

This is trivial. Simply load the page, open the dev tools of the browser, select the common.js file, and set a break-point at the first line of the function. Now, **reload** the page. The break-point will **persist** the reload, and execution will be paused.

### How to do it on the nested page:

Now, in Chrome and Firefox (Firebug), the break-point that was set above (for the main page), will also work for the nested page. Both pages use the same JS file, and setting a break point in that file will apply for both pages automatically. Unfortunately, this rule does not apply to IE.

And even worse, even if I set the break point subsequently, and then **reload the iframe only**, the break-point will **not** persist.

So, I don't know how to pause execution for the nested page in IE. Can it be done? (I'm dealing with this by manually setting a `debugger;` at the beginning of the function, but I would love to be able to set the break-point via the dev tools in IE, if that's possible.)

Comment: Visual studio is very good at debugging ie, but i don't know if it can handle this situation... it's what I'd try if i needed it tho

Comment: @MartinJespersen I'm in the PHP camp `:-|`. Installing VS just for this would be an overkill.

Comment: what version of ie are you using for this?

Comment: @MartinJespersen IE9, of course. I'm not even sure if prior versions of IE had usable dev tools.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas IE8 was the first version to have dev tools and Microsoft released the plugin for IE7 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: @mattytommo They probably sucked `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas haha to be fair IE8 dev tools were pretty much as good as the ones in IE9 :)

Comment: Is this for compatibility testing?

Comment: Couldn't you use a hard-coded [`debugger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bwt76sk.aspx) breakpoint?

Comment: @Martijn That's what I'm doing. (Read the last paragraph of my question.) However, I'm working on an online demo application which is deployed for testing purposes, and every change in the JavaScript code has to be made by a server-side programmer (not me) with whom I communicate via e-mail. I cannot add that statement myself - I have to send an e-mail to that other guy, who then has to make the change in the file and upload it to the demo server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can come to a solution is to set a breakpoint within the loadIFrame() function on the main page and then 'step in' until the nested page's Common.js file is loaded.  In a more complicated example you would then be able to set your breakpoints within the new Common.js file and they would work correctly until the next time the iframe is loaded, when they would all be lost again.

Comment: Your first paragraph does not make sense. The "load" event of the iframe element is triggered *after* the nested page and the script have been loaded. *** As for your second paragraph, that is not possible. My code is setting the `src` property of the iframe element. One cannot step into the nested page's JS code, from here.

Comment: Let me clarify what I mean.  Load your example page and open IE's F12 Developer Tools and navigate to the Script tab, and then put a breakpoint at line 26 [document.getElementById( 'IFrame').src = 'nestedpage.html';]  Now you will see that only MainPage.html and Common.js are loaded.  Hit 'Step In' until you reach NestedPage.html.  Now you see that NestedPage.html and another Common.js are loaded.  By putting the breakpoint at that line 26 it will always persist and you will always have an entry point to the loading of the NestedPage and its Common.js file.

Comment: Wow! It does work. (I tried stepping in from the `.src` assignment statement before, but I couldn't get it to work.) Also, this method does not work in Chrome. However, it does work in IE `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, please transfer the bounty I received and give it to paulH whom deserves it, as his answer was within the bounty period. I was glad to help out, but would be more glad to see the right person be rewarded for a valid solution to this question. +1 for paulH.

Comment: @arttronics I'm sorry, that cannot be done. Rewarding a bounty is an irreversible process.

Comment: Well, at least there's two methods on this page for your most interesting question.

Comment: Happy to help!  And no worries about the bounty, I'd forgotten there was a bounty on the question anyway until you mentioned it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have IE9 to test, but perhaps you can treat `common.js` file as a separate asset for the iframe page? I believe that's why it works in other browsers since those files must be ***tagged or labeled*** by the browser some how.

An example is to append `?iframePage` to the end of `common.js` on the iframe page. At least in Firefox is shows an asset loaded as `common.js?iframePage`. Everything past the query string is ignored by the browser but otherwise the JavaScript is loaded with that ***exact*** name.

Another example is to make a copy of `common.js` and renamed it to `commonClone.js` which is then used for the iframe page.

Either example might allow you to set the break-point **twice** in IE9, one for each asset.

That said, there's nothing stopping you from creating **iframe only breakpoints** that are independent of `common.js` file that the **parent page** is using.. This method, let's call it **parallel break-point**, allows for asynchronous debugging of JavaScript since the **iframe page** and the **parent page** are processing JavaScript independently yet may be working in tandem.

Reference for this method is from **official source** MSDN Library: **Using the F12 Developer Tools to Debug JavaScript Errors** section **[Managing Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#managingbreakpoints)** that shows how to perform breakpoints on multiple JavaScript files.

According to a [recent forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/db6bba96-d590-4e56-b33d-991581671bae/) at the IE9 Developers Forum, the solution to prevent reloading of JavaScript files when used for debugging is to use the **inline event handler** instead of **attachEvent** as shown in this example:

```
replace (or comment it out)

$(document).onload(function(){ mycustomonload functions});

with

<body onload="mycustomonload functions">
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "IE9 only breakpoints"?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, A clarification: "IE9 only breakpoints" means to create breakpoints in the iframe page when debugging using that browser. For example, you may wish to have a breakpoint in the parent page that is not browser specific, but the iframe page may contain a breakpoint that is browser specific (e.g., IE9). I will update the above answer to reflect **iframe only breakpoints** since that's more clear.

Comment: But the problem is that the code executes on page load, so it's not possible to set the break-point manually on time. And if I set the break-point subsequently, and then reload the iframe, the break-point doesn't persist. (I explained this in my question.)

Comment: The [Managing Breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#managingbreakpoints) section I read doesn't mention that it wouldn't persist so I was expecting that it would, especially for multiple JavaScript files that should be in the cache to then allow such breakpoints from resetting. Perhaps **always refresh from server** browser setting can be changed so file in cache is used? Besides that, I am out of ideas for persisting breakpoints.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I checked the "Network" tab in IE9's tools. When reloading the iframe, IE receives 304-Not-Modified-responses from the server, so it loads the files from its cache.

Comment: Humm, I came across this [recent solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/db6bba96-d590-4e56-b33d-991581671bae/) from a senior MVP member in the IE9 Developers Forum that seems to address the reloading issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a solution to my problem. Based on that suggestion, I made a new demo, but it still doesn't work. See here: http://www.ecmazing.com/misc/pause-execution/mainpage2.html

Comment: I downloaded your **mainpage2.html** and accompanying files, and after using method **commonClone1.js** and **commonClone2.js** for each iframe page I was able in IE8 (still on XP) to set breakpoint. Page refresh will retain both iframe contents. Pressing enter in address bar will reset page, but breakpoints persist in form of **yellow explanation point** since file is not loaded (breakpoint is on standby). If this method works for you, perhaps loading **cloned common.js** via actually cloning script and loading it using different name is possible, thus avoiding physical cloned files.

Comment: Following your guidelines, I've created an [updated demo](http://www.ecmazing.com/misc/pause-execution/mainpage2.html). Yes, it works now - the break-points are persistent now. The problem with non-persistent break-points seems to only occur if both the nested page and top-level page share the *same* JavaScript file.

Comment: I've also created [this demo](http://www.ecmazing.com/misc/pause-execution/mainpage3.html), where I add *different* query strings to the URL's of the `common.js` file (as you suggested in your answer). This makes it work as well. This is also the best solution to this issue. The only down-side is that, because of the different query strings, the same file is treated as two different resources by the browser, which means that the browser will download the same file twice. This would be an issue in production, especially if the file is large. However, in testing, this is a great solution.

Comment: The downside may be addressed by using jQuery to clone the **common.js** file client side, then load it as an asset using query string name? I dunno, but that might be a solution. Loading of the cloned **common.js** script is then done using JavaScript and appending it to the document. Extensive tests to see if it's stable outside debug environment is important too, since possible issue with cloned variables and other cloned script elements may cause unwanted issues... but the cloned scripts are bound to their perspective HTML pages so this should not be an issue.

Comment: That's not necessary, since I need this behavior only during testing. I have a demo application which I use for testing, and I can just add the query string to the problematic JS file URL temporarily. Later, in production, I just remove the query string. That's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this solely for compatibility testing then have you tried using [IETab plugin](http://www.ietab.net/) for Chrome?

This emulates IE's rendering engine while allowing you to use the Chrome debugger.

If this isn't good enough then I think you've hit an impasse, IE dev tools just aren't sophisticated enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, that IETab plugin did not solve my problem. In my application, there exists an unwanted vertical scrollbar in IE9. However, if I load the page with IETab, that scrollbar is not present, even though I've set "IE9 mode" in IETab's settings. This means that IETab doesn't reliably emulate IE, and therefore, I cannot use it as a solution.

Comment: Hm. My worry was that perhaps it wouldn't emulate IE's JavaScript engine. But are you saying the page style is different too?

Comment: Well, the difference in appearance is the result of some JavaScript code that I'm executing. (I'm setting the dimensions of certain elements on the page.) So, it could very well be that the layout engine is emulated well, but that the JavaScript engine is the cause of the differences in appearance. In any way, I need a 100% reliable solution, and IETab doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Fair enough. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: I don't really think the downvote was necessary, whoever that was.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, if you could restructure your Html and JavaScript code, you could only reference `common.js` from the parent page and make both the main and the nested page use the same JavaScript function.

That way one break point would satisfy both scenarios.

Comment: Well, that's certainly an interesting idea. However, regarding this thread, your answer is really only a comment, since it doesn't provide a solution for my current state. But thanks for the suggestion. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

To debug iframes in IE, and be able to set and retain breakpoints, you could open the iframe address in its own ie tab/window. This is not possible/straightforward however if the iframe communicates with its parent.

Comment: Yea, the JS code of the page loaded in the iframe, does need access to the parent window `:(`. Also, in my current scenario, I'm setting the dimensions of the iframe, and the page loaded in it, depends on this. However, this is a good idea, and it might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you at least are using IE Debuggy Bar. Update your common.js file with this code

```
function func () {
    if(typeof window.parent.debug !== "undefined"){
        window.parent.debug();
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'h1')[0].style.color = 'red';
}


function debug(){
    var a = "break here";
}
```

set break point to `var a = "break here";` after your main page loads. When you hit Load Iframe button js will stop on that line. Use call stack to navigate to previous javascript instruction (line) which should be in common.js file in nestedpage.html. Now set another break point where ever you'd like and hit continue in debugger, or use STEP feature

== UPDATE ===

BTW, to answer your question, why break point cannot be persisted in iframe, think this way. Each time you click on "Load IFrame" button, old instance of `window` object is disposed in memory and with it all break points and new is created with new common.js instance. Same would happen if you would call `windows.open("http://......");`

Also keep in mind even you have same file loaded in both `window(s)`, it is loaded in two different execution frames in browser. you can run two browser instances of same browser but they are not showing same page in window. Tho, there are things which are shared, like cookies but that is out of scope of this topic.

Comment: There is no need for all this. There is a `debugger;` statement for this purpose - I already mentioned that in my original question. I would like to know how to pause the execution *without* having to manually edit the JavaScript file.

Comment: There is no way if you are not using advanced IDE :) I'm using PHPStorm and WebStorm. They have excellent integration debug plugin for browsers. Problem here is that your common.js file is not loaded in IFrame at the moment you would like to have it in builtin browser debugger.

Comment: If you don't want to download any IDE guys here suggested the only option you have is example I suggested you.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The code does execute. The problem is that the break-point does not persist. When reloading a top-most window, the break-point persist, but when reloading an iframe, the break-point does not persist - that's the problem.

Comment: Excellent! then you can set set remote server debug, just go to Debug Configuration. Create new `JavaScript Debug > Remote` configuration, and setup which source file has which URL in browser. Also specify which remote URL should be opened in browser when you start debugging session... I'm sure you will manage to set it up.

Comment: *"I'm sure you will manage to set it up."* - Hm, I'm not so sure about that `:)` There is [this wiki](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm), but I'm currently not motivated to read it thoroughly.

Comment: Believe me it's worth to try, it's great "remote" javascript debugger

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout() for pause javascript for perticular time...

Comment: In my question I mention that I already use `debugger;` as a solution. But, ideally, I would like to pause the execution without having to manually edit the JavaScript file.